# MsBuild copy file after build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild, csproj

I want to copy an xml file from the main directory to `bin\Debug` after building the project, but my solution doesn't work. I edited `.csproj` file and added:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
     <Copy SourceFiles="Controllers.xml" DestinationFolder="\bin\Debug" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

What am I doing wrong? The build is successful.

Comment: What is the build output for this MsBuild target? I suspect you need to put `$MSBuildProjectDirectory\Controllers.xml`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your destination folder is (most likely) wrong. If you specify it with a leading backslash, it is actually just a shortform for `<current-drive-letter>\bin\Debug` (making it effectively an absolute path, like `C:\bin\Debug`).

Either use `bin\Debug`, or better yet use the `OutputPath` variable, which is set to either `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` depending on your build configuration.

Example:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
     <Copy SourceFiles="Controllers.xml" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 6):

Is the xml file in your project?
 Then one of its properties is CopyToOutputDirectory. Set it to CopyAlways and when  the project builds the file will be copied out to bin\debug.

Comment: Syntax for VSCode users:
 <ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Controllers.xml">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
 </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the full path. I suspect the MsBuild copy task is running from the "Default path" of Visual Studio, and the file can not be found. Also, you most likely want the file to end up in the build target directory.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)Controllers.xml" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```