# TFS Build not copying files correctly at end of build

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I am currently trialling Visual Studio Online with an On-Premises build server. I have managed to move a number of projects into VSOnline but for some reason have hit a brick wall with one.

The project appears to build correctly but when I get to the end of the build I get the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (4291): The command "copy *.dll ........\PROJECT NAME\bin\Debug /y" exited with code 1.

I have deleted the project and re-created to be sure there was nothing wrong with my initial setup. As far as I can tell I have followed exactly the same process to create this project as I have 2 others that have both worked perfectly.

When I take the MSBuild command that is actually executed and run that directly on the build server it works fine.

Is there any way to get more information about what is going wrong? Has anyone else come across something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Post Build events for several of the projects were causing the issue when building on TFS.

I added

`IF "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"=="true" ( copy command here )`

to the Post Build Events so that they only run when building in Visual STudio and are ignored in TFS Build.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your post build events to [`AfterBuild`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12386067/147211).

Always use properties instead of hard-coded names. E.g. use `$(Configuration)` instead of Debug or Release.