# Slowcheetah XML transform for c# Windows Store / Metro / win-store app

Tags: xml, windows-store-apps, slowcheetah, xdt-transform, xdt

I have installed SlowCheetah from the extensions gallery, then from nuget (then uninstalled and reinstalled from nuget).

**It works !** ***Almost ;)***

That is **it is transforming the relevant files and copying them to the bin/[nameofconfig e.g. Debug / Release]/ folder**

However, when running the app locally the file that gets used is that found in e.g.

D:\Projects[projectname]\bin\Debug\ **AppX**

And *this file* remains as **the original untransformed file**.

**What's the easiest way to get this working when I hit F5** *as the extensions description claims it should* (for a win store app).

I am guessing a copy file task in the .csproj would do the trick - anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this *seems* to work (will have to test it for "Create App Package" later and update this answer then)...

I added an **AfterBuild copy file task** as follows :

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)\PortiLog.Config.xml" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\AppX" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
```

And **Voila** !!! se fantastique non?

My SlowCheetah transformed xml file is now copied correctly to the AppX folder which is *the correct place when debugging locally* and corresponds to

```
Package.Current.InstalledLocation
```

Thanks to @Christian.K for the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12386067/661584) which lead me to my solution !